# Process runs fine while running through process screen but not under automated schedule

Tags: acumatica

I have a process that I'm trying to schedule.  When the schedule runs, I get the following error:

```
       Message: Error #199: You are not currently logged in.

Date/Time: 09/06/2015 10:20
Platform: 
Browser: 

Source: PX.Data
Target Site: Int32 GetCurrentCompany()
Stack Trace:    at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.GetCurrentCompany()
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.getCompanyID(String tableName, companySetting& setting)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.getRestriction(String table, String alias, Boolean mainRestriction, Boolean isRightJoin, Nullable`1 effectiveCid)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.alterText(String text, Int32 start, Int32 stop, Boolean isTopLevelQuery)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.alterText(String text, Int32 start, Int32 stop, Boolean isTopLevelQuery)
   at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.Select(PXGraph graph, BqlCommand command, Int32 topCount, PXView view, PXDataValue[] pars)
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.ProviderSelect(BqlCommand command, Int32 topCount, PXView view, PXDataValue[] pars)
   at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)
   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectBase`1.selectBound[Resultset](BqlCommand command, Boolean readOnly, PXGraph graph, Int32 startRow, Int32 totalRows, Object[] currents, Object[] pars)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectBase`1.select[Resultset](BqlCommand command, Boolean readOnly, PXGraph graph, Int32 startRow, Int32 totalRows, Object[] pars)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectReadonly`2.SelectWindowed[Resultset](PXGraph graph, Int32 startRow, Int32 totalRows, Object[] pars)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectReadonly`2.Select[Resultset](PXGraph graph, Object[] pars)
   at Exosoft.MP.MikePero.Graphs.RexApiMaint.GetCustomerByCD(String id)
```

The process runs fine when I run it through my process screen but not under an automated schedule.

Error happens when I call the below...

```
PXSelectReadonly<PX.Objects.AR.Customer, Where<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctCD, Equal<Required<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctCD>>>>.Select(this, id);
```

The graph and the graph it calls to process are custom based on a custom table I created.  I have added CompanyID and the other audit fields to the custom table. This is how I am calling it

```
public class SyncRexApiProcess : PXGraph<SyncRexApiProcess>
{

    public PXCancel<RexApiLogin> Cancel;
    public PXProcessing<RexApiLogin> RexApiLogins;

    public SyncRexApiProcess()
    {
        RexApiLogins.SetProcessCaption("Sync From Rex Api Login");
        RexApiLogins.SetProcessAllCaption("Sync From All Rex Api Logins");
        RexApiLogins.SetProcessDelegate<RexApiMaint>(
            delegate(RexApiMaint graph, RexApiLogin login)
            {
                graph.Clear();
                Func<Task> task = async () =>
                {
                    await graph.SyncAPIDataAsync(login);
                };
                task().Wait();

            });
    }

}
```

Comment: post your code for a better understanding. Try attaching the process to debugger and run through the schedule so that you can debug the code to find the issue.

Comment: the stack trace and the error says that somehow there is an issue with the login. the line of code you posted doesnt have any issue. I believe when Acumcatica tries to execute it against the DB the company ID is not available for the graph. Use PX.Common.PXContext.GetSlot<int?>("singleCompanyID"); in immediate window to find the currently logged in company.

Comment: PX.Common.PXContext.GetSlot<int?>("singleCompanyID"); is returning null

Comment: Okay, that means the issue is with the login session of that particular graph and not with the line of code mentioned there.

Comment: Please see above my code from the process graph calling a method on my other graph.  What considerations do I have to make regarding the login session, do I have to initialise something first?

Comment: Code looks OK. so you are getting the problem in RexApiMaint , rite? Try the code without Task Parallel processing, as from my previous experience i got some issues while multi threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using async/await, your code will run in a different thread, which isn't guaranteed to be initialized properly with session variables. I don't believe Acumatica guarantees any sort of thread-safety with the graph or any of the caches, so you should separate any code that interacts with it from your asynchronous operations.

Furthermore, I don't see any reason to use an asynchronous operation; it will just make your life harder in this case - just run your API synchronization from the main thread. If you want to run multiple operations at once, and wait for them to return, then isolate these operations from the graph and caches.