# Concurrent Acumatica API contexts cause errors in GetSchema()

Tags: acumatica

We have a web service that accepts requests from an outside site, then uses the Acumatica API to add or update Customer records based on the requests.  This is working fine when we receive one request at a time.  The problem is that the outside site batches up their requests and then sends multiple requests simultaneously.  That means we end up with two or more requests running simultaneously, which means multiple logins and multiple contexts all happening at once.  This ends up almost always producing a vague "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at one of the many GetSchema() calls.  I've also seen some Lock Violation errors, like: "Error #147: Another process has added 'CSAnswers' record. Your changes will be lost."

I've created a test case below that can duplicate this occurrence by firing 3 asynchronous web requests to the same single web page that makes all the API calls.  One other wrinkle is that it seems to always produce the error when I run it after not running it for a while.  If I run it immediately again, then it usually succeeds.  That makes me think that maybe something is cached in the subsequent calls, so it runs faster, and then doesn't run into itself???  I don't know, I tried adding some delays to see if that made it happen more often on the subsequent runs, but it didn't.

Does anyone know if Acumatica API definitely does not support asynchronous / simultaneous contexts?  I only saw [this post on automated scheduling where Gabriel mentioned some thread safety concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744041/process-runs-fine-while-running-through-process-screen-but-not-under-automated-s/30805793#30805793), but not sure that's the same thing.

The code is two ASP.Net pages in VB.  Default.aspx is just some buttons used to create the single and simultaneous calls to CreateReservation.aspx.

We are using Acumatica Version 4.20.2063 and IIS 8.5 and I think pipeline is .net 4.0 integrated. Thanks!

Default.aspx.vb:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="AcumaticaTesting._Default" Async="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnStartOne" Text="Run One" OnClick="btnStartOne_Click" />
    <br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnStartAsynch" Text="Run Three (Asynchronous)" OnClick="btnStartAsynch_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.vb (relevant methods)

```
Protected m_webRequest1 As WebClient
Protected m_webRequest2 As WebClient
Protected m_webRequest3 As WebClient
Protected m_webAddress As String = "http://localhost:61343/CreateReservation.aspx"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub btnStartOne_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(m_webAddress)

    m_webRequest1 = New WebClient()
    AddHandler m_webRequest1.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf OpenReadCallback
    m_webRequest1.OpenReadAsync(uri)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnStartAsynch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(m_webAddress)

    m_webRequest1 = New WebClient()
    AddHandler m_webRequest1.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf OpenReadCallback
    m_webRequest1.OpenReadAsync(Uri)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(CInt(Int(50))) ' milliseconds

    m_webRequest2 = New WebClient()
    AddHandler m_webRequest2.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf OpenReadCallback
    m_webRequest2.OpenReadAsync(uri)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(CInt(Int(50))) ' milliseconds

    m_webRequest3 = New WebClient()
    AddHandler m_webRequest3.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf OpenReadCallback
    m_webRequest3.OpenReadAsync(uri)
End Sub

' THIS IS JUST A CALLBACK FOR THE ASYNCHRONOUS CALLS, ALL IT DOES IS SET A STATUS MESSAGE
Protected Sub OpenReadCallback(sender As Object, e As OpenReadCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim reply As Stream = Nothing
    Dim s As StreamReader = Nothing

    Try

        reply = CType(e.Result, Stream)
        s = New StreamReader(reply)
        Console.WriteLine(s.ReadToEnd())
    Finally

        If Not s Is Nothing Then

            s.Close()
        End If

        If Not reply Is Nothing Then

            reply.Close()
        End If
    End Try
    lblMessage.Text = "Received result"
End Sub
```

CreateReservation.aspx (relevant methods)

```
' HELPER METHOD
Protected Function CreateValue(screenField As AcumaticaAPI.Field, newVal As String) As Value
    Return CreateValue(screenField, newVal, False)
End Function

' HELPER METHOD
Protected Function CreateValue(screenField As AcumaticaAPI.Field, newVal As String, addCommit As Boolean) As Value
    Dim theValue As Value = New Value()
    theValue.LinkedCommand = screenField
    theValue.Value = newVal

    If addCommit Then
        theValue.Commit = True
    End If

    Return theValue
End Function

' PAGE_LOAD MAKES ALL THE ACTUAL API CALLS
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim delayAmt As Integer = 4000

    ' Initialize the random-number generator.
    Randomize()
    Dim nameEnd As Integer = Now.Millisecond
    Dim fullName As String = "Doe, John" + nameEnd.ToString()

    ' STEP 1: Login
    Dim context1 As AcumaticaAPI.Screen
    context1 = New AcumaticaAPI.Screen
    context1.CookieContainer = New System.Net.CookieContainer()
    context1.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    context1.EnableDecompression = True
    context1.Timeout = 1000000
    context1.Url = ACUMATICA_URL
    Dim login1 As LoginResult = context1.Login(ACUMATICA_USER, ACUMATICA_PWD)

    ' STEP 2 : See if customer exists
    Dim CR303000 As CR303000Content = context1.CR303000GetSchema()
    context1.CR303000Clear()

    Dim nameFilter As Filter = New Filter()
    nameFilter.Field = CR303000.AccountSummary.BusinessAccountName
    nameFilter.Condition = FilterCondition.Equals
    nameFilter.Value = fullName

    Dim searchfilters() As Filter = {nameFilter}
    Dim searchCommands() As Command = {CR303000.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount, CR303000.DetailsMainContact.Phone1, CR303000.DetailsMainContact.Phone2}
    Dim searchResult As String()() = context1.CR303000Export(searchCommands, searchfilters, 0, False, False)

    ' STEP 3 CREATE CUSTOMER
    Dim AR303000 As AR303000Content = context1.AR303000GetSchema()
    context1.AR303000Clear()

    ' create customer with just name for now
    Dim nameVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerName, fullName)

    ' other fields required for Customer
    Dim classVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.CustomerClass, "DEFAULT")
    Dim statementCycleVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.StatementCycleID, "ENDOFMONTH")
    Dim statementTypeVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.BillingSettingsPrintAndEmailSettings.StatementType, "Open Item")
    Dim cashDiscountAccountVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GLAccountsCashDiscountAccount.CashDiscountAccount, "10103")
    Dim creditVerificationVal As Value = CreateValue(AR303000.GeneralInfoCreditVerificationRulesCreditVerification.CreditVerification, "Disabled")

    ' execute insert with just name and required fields
    Dim insertCommands As Command() = {nameVal, classVal, statementCycleVal, statementTypeVal, cashDiscountAccountVal, creditVerificationVal, AR303000.Actions.Save}
    Dim insertResult As AR303000Content() = context1.AR303000Submit(insertCommands)

    ' STEP 4 : Find the newly created Customer record
    Dim CR303000_2 As CR303000Content = context1.CR303000GetSchema()
    context1.CR303000Clear()

    Dim nameFilter_2 As Filter = New Filter()
    nameFilter_2.Field = CR303000_2.AccountSummary.BusinessAccountName
    nameFilter_2.Condition = FilterCondition.Equals
    nameFilter_2.Value = fullName

    Dim searchfilters_2() As Filter = {nameFilter_2}
    Dim searchCommands_2() As Command = {CR303000_2.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount, CR303000_2.DetailsMainContact.Phone1, CR303000_2.DetailsMainContact.Phone2}
    Dim searchResult_2 As String()() = context1.CR303000Export(searchCommands_2, searchfilters_2, 0, False, False)
    Dim newCustomerID As String = searchResult_2(0)(0)

    ' STEP 5 : Add Business Acct fields
    Dim CR303000_3 As CR303000Content = context1.CR303000GetSchema()
    context1.CR303000Clear()

    ' create key field
    Dim baKeyVal As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.AccountSummary.BusinessAccount, newCustomerID.ToString())
    Dim baClassIDVal As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.DetailsCRM.ClassID, "DEFAULT")

    ' create custom fields to update at same time
    Dim passwordName As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.Attributes.Attribute, CUST_ATTRIBUTE_ID_PASSWORD)
    Dim passwordVal As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.Attributes.Value, "-------", True)
    Dim secretQuestionName As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.Attributes.Attribute, CUST_ATTRIBUTE_ID_SECRET_QUESTION)
    Dim secretQuestionVal As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.Attributes.Value, "QQQQQQ", True)
    Dim secretAnswerName As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.Attributes.Attribute, CUST_ATTRIBUTE_ID_SECRET_ANSWER)
    Dim secretAnswerVal As Value = CreateValue(CR303000_3.Attributes.Value, "AAAAAAA", True)

    ' execute update
    Dim updateBACommands As Command() = {baKeyVal, baClassIDVal, passwordName, passwordVal, secretQuestionName, secretQuestionVal, secretAnswerName, secretAnswerVal, CR303000_3.Actions.Save}
    Dim updateBAResult As CR303000Content() = context1.CR303000Submit(updateBACommands)
End Sub
```

The full exception that I consistently get is this, but it can occur at different GetSchema() calls:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException was unhandled by user code
Actor=""
HResult=-2146233087
Lang=""
Message=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.GetScreenInfo(String screenId, Boolean appendDescriptors)
at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.GetScreenInfoWithServiceCommands(Boolean appendDescriptors, String screenID)
at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Get(String id, SchemaMode mode)
at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGeneric.GetSchema(String screenID)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Node=""
Role=""
Source=System.Web.Services
StackTrace:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at AcumaticaTesting.AcumaticaAPI.Screen.AR303000GetSchema() in C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AcumaticaTesting\AcumaticaTesting\Web References\AcumaticaAPI\Reference.vb:line 671
   at AcumaticaTesting.CreateReservation.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AcumaticaTesting\AcumaticaTesting\CreateReservation.aspx.vb:line 59
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
InnerException:
```

Comment: What version/build number are you running?

Comment: Could you also specify the IIS version and IIS pipeline mode you're using?

Comment: @Philippe Sorry, Acumatica version is Version 4.20.2063

Comment: @SergRogovtsev IIS 8.5 and I think its .net 4.0 integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug that was fixed in version 5.20.1227.

The cause was a race condition that would occur when the system is building the screen schema. This schema is only built when the App Pool has been recycled and this is why you are experiencing it mostly when the system has been idle for a certain period of time. Manually recycling the App Pool should force the behaviour to happen.

Comment: Great! I will look into whether we can upgrade to that version or higher. Thank you!